# get_categories hierarchical order like wp_list_categories - with name, slug & link to edit cat

Tags: categories

I need to find a way to list all categories - empty or not - in a hierarchial list - like wp_list_categories - also showing the slug, cat name and a link to edit in the admin.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$args = array(
        'orderby'   => 'name',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'    => '0',
  );

$categories = get_categories($args);

foreach( $categories as $category ) { 

    $cat_ID = $category->term_id;
    $cat_name = $category->name;
    #$cat_desc = $category->description; if ( !$cat_desc { $cat_desc = 'Nada!' } );
    $cat_count = $category->count;

    echo '<p><strong>'.$cat_name.'</strong>';
    echo ' / <a href="' . get_category_link( $cat_ID ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $cat_name ) . '" ' . '>View ( '. $cat_count . ' posts )</a>  ';
    #echo ' / Desc: '. $cat_desc . '';
    echo ' / <a href="'. get_admin_url().'edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=category&tag_ID='.$cat_ID.'&post_type=post" title="Edit Category">Edit</a>';
    echo '</p>';  

}
```

All is good, but not nicely ordered - just an alphabetical list.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

output as unordered list:

```
<?php

    hierarchical_category_tree( 0 ); // the function call; 0 for all categories; or cat ID  

function hierarchical_category_tree( $cat ) {
    // wpse-41548 // alchymyth // a hierarchical list of all categories //

  $next = get_categories('hide_empty=false&orderby=name&order=ASC&parent=' . $cat);

  if( $next ) :    
    foreach( $next as $cat ) :
    echo '<ul><li><strong>' . $cat->name . '</strong>';
    echo ' / <a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $cat->name ) . '" ' . '>View ( '. $cat->count . ' posts )</a>  '; 
    echo ' / <a href="'. get_admin_url().'edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=category&tag_ID='.$cat->term_id.'&post_type=post" title="Edit Category">Edit</a>'; 
    hierarchical_category_tree( $cat->term_id );
    endforeach;    
  endif;

  echo '</li></ul>'; echo "\n";
}  
?>
```

Comment: genius! - hide_empty seems to require a numeric value to work, the rest is spot on - thanks!

Comment: perhaps unrelated to my original question, but how could I determine the "level" of the category hierarchy each category is on - for example in a 3 level hierarchy, I'd need to get 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GbZFnytw - depth output added as css class of ul tag

Comment: amazing - is there any way to nest the ul / li's - so that they all wrap around - I'd like to try and get them into an accordion type open / close navigation?

Comment: by nesting I meant <ul><li><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul> - I guess you figured that...

Comment: new code http://pastebin.com/TTvYPKPH  -  corrected with added code for structured html output - ignore the old pastebin http://pastebin.com/GbZFnytw

Comment: thanks again, could I PM you a link to a page, I have another question, but don't want to make the URL public?

Comment: no problem - just use the email linked with my username.

Comment: where do I find this email?

Comment: @Michael Very nice! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly updated version of [Michael’s answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41559/737) to use the more generic [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) (so you can get custom taxonomies, in this case I wanted the WooCommerce product category taxonomy of `product_cat`).

```
echo hierarchical_term_tree();

function hierarchical_term_tree($category = 0)
{
    $r = '';

    $args = array(
        'parent' => $category,
    );

    $next = get_terms('product_cat', $args);

    if ($next) {
        $r .= '<ul>';

        foreach ($next as $cat) {
            $r .= '<li><a href="' . get_term_link($cat->slug, $cat->taxonomy) . '" title="' . sprintf(__("View all products in %s"), $cat->name) . '" ' . '>' . $cat->name . ' (' . $cat->count . ')' . '</a>';
            $r .= $cat->term_id !== 0 ? hierarchical_term_tree($cat->term_id) : null;
        }
        $r .= '</li>';

        $r .= '</ul>';
    }

    return $r;
}
```

Simplified a little to take out the edit link etc. You can add those as required.

Comment: Error : PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string.  On this line : foreach ($next as $cat)  .

Comment: This looks nice. How could I modify it to actually show the starting term at the top of the list? Currently, it shows all of the child terms, right? I'm using a non-0 term ID, ie. a valid term ID, not just all of them.

Comment: @deadlyhifi Nice! Got the job done for me! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
$args = array(

    'hide_empty'         => 0,
    'echo'               => 1,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'hierarchical'  =>1,
    'show_count' => 1,

);

function add_class_wp_list_categories($wp_list_categories) {
        $pattern = '/<li class="/is';
        $replacement = '<li class="first ';
        return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $wp_list_categories);
}
add_filter('wp_list_categories','add_class_wp_list_categories');

echo wp_list_categories( $args );
```

Answer (score -1):

Hmm I think you need to include `'hierarchical' => 1,` in your args list. Also you have one comma too much at the end of the args list. After the last argument you do not need a comma :)

Here's a complete example:

```
$args = array(
        'orderby'   => 'name', 
        'order'     => 'ASC', 
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'hide_empty'    => '0'
  );
```

Comment: Read more at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories :)

Comment: Thanks - but this does not order them hierarchically - the codex states: -- When true, the results will include sub-categories that are empty, as long as those sub-categories have sub-categories that are not empty. The default is true. Valid values: