# Show full category tree for a year with all post titles?

Tags: wp-query, categories, archives, hierarchical

Is it possible to print all categories used for a specific year in a hierarchical tree with all the post titles underneath each category title?

How?

Comment: If a post has multiple categories, should its title be printed multiple times?

Comment: Is this different to your question yesterday? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/237853/94267

Comment: @cjbj Yes it should. And no, I should delete the other one. I changed my mind how I want it.

Answer (score 0):

The start is easy. Let's fetch all the posts from 2015:

```
$posts = new WP_Query( 'year=2015' );
```

Now, we have an array of post objects, which we must sort into categories, duplicating them if they have multipe categories. The result goes into a multidimensional array.

```
$categorized_posts = array ();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
  $post_cats = wp_get_post_categories ($post->ID, array('fields' => names));
  foreach ($post_cats as $post_cat) {
    $categorized_posts[$postcat][] = $post->ID;
    }
  }
```

So `$categorized_posts` is an array with category names and for every category name there is an array of ID's of the corresponding post. What's missing is a hierarchical tree. We're going to loop through all categories, printing them along the way with the corresponding post titles. To do this hierarchically we use [the recursive function found here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41548/get-categories-hierarchical-order-like-wp-list-categories-with-name-slug-li), which we modify to output post titles.

```
// this goes in the template where you want the tree to be printed
wpse237979_hierarchical_category_tree (0, $categorized_posts );

// this goes in functions.php
function wpse237979_hierarchical_category_tree ( $cat, $categorized_posts ) {
  $next = get_categories('hide_empty=false&orderby=name&order=ASC&parent=' . $cat);
  if ($next) {    
    foreach ($next as $cat) {
      if (array_key_exists($cat,$categorized_posts)) {
        echo '<ul><li><strong>' . $cat->name . '</strong>';
        // now loop through the gathered ID's of posts belonging to this category
        $current_cat_posts = $categorized_posts[$cat];
        foreach ($current_cat_posts as $current_cat_post) {
          $this_post = get_post ($current_cat_post);
          echo '<h2>' . $this_post->post_title . '<h2>';
          }
        }
    wpse237979_hierarchical_category_tree( $cat->term_id, $categorized_posts );
    }   
  }
  echo '</li></ul>'; echo "\n";
}
```

Note: I didn't actually test this code, so some debugging may be necessary, but I trust you get the general idea.